Azure document intelligence - not extracting list correctly
I have a document type that I am trying to build a custom extraction model for.
The document has a section with a list of "selected options" that looks like this:

The number of these options is dynamic and can be in any order.
My goal is to extract these so I can programmatically interpret these as a list.
What I've done in the labelling is to define a table with a single column, and add a row for each option:

I've repeated this process for 5 documents, each having different options. Some have enough to go onto a new line on the page.
This sort of works, but what I end up getting back from the API is:
option1 = "Some option"
option2 = "Some other option"
option3 = "selected\nYet another option"

Note the \n in the 3rd option. This is pretty weird & initially I thought it must be reading the text from left to right (despite assigning each option text to the individual cells), but then I realised if that was the case the the third option would read "Yet another\nselected\noption"
So then I tried using drawn regions for the labelling instead of selecting the text:

But that resulted in the exact same result.
Is there a better way to label/train with this scenario where I want to get a list?
I'm using the API Version: 2024-07-31 (preview) and I'm using the Azure.AI.DocumentIntelligence nuget package to call the API.
The values of the table field are populated in the ValueList property of the DocumentField object, where each item has a single dictionary item of "Option", "Option text" (where "Option" is the column heading defined in the labelling/model)
